# Getting null in request.getParameter("something")

Tags: java, spring, jsp

My application (Spring, JSP) cannot read the value from drop down box, always getting null as a parameter.

JSP:

```
<select>
<c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
<option value = "$country.id_country">${country.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView addOrganization() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add");
        Organization organization = new Organization();
        modelAndView.addObject("organization", organization);
        List<Country> countries = countryService.listOfCountries();
        modelAndView.addObject("countries", countries);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addingConfirm(Organization organization, HttpServletRequest request)
{
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("confirm");
            Integer id_country = null;
        if (request.getParameter("сountry") != null
                && !request.getParameter("сountry").equals("")) {
            id_country = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("сountry"));
            organization.setCountry(id_country);
        }
        organizationService.addOrganization(organization);
        String message = "Organization was successfully added.";
        modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

So, parameter `country` is always `null`.

Comment: have you checked what `countryService.listOfCountries()` returns? Is it null?

Comment: Nope, it's not null, because in UI i see the correct drop down box with countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` will not post without a `name` attribute.

Also, your `value` attribute on `<option>` is missing some braces {}.

And you should always(!) make sure to escape any dynamic text you generate, by wrapping `${country.name}` in a `<c:out>`.

```
<select name="country">
  <c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
    <option value="${country.id_country}"><c:out value="${country.name}"/></option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

If `id_country` is a String, you should even consider wrapping that in a `<c:out>`. The wrapping of `id_country` and `name` is optional if you are absolutely(!) sure that they can be trusted to not contain cross-site scripting attacks, but it's a good idea to get into the habit of escaping all text values.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your example of code and explanation! It works. You save my day.

Comment: You're welcome. Please up-vote and/or accept answer so I can get some nice reputation ;-)